# Like Operator cannot detect the character in string

Tags: string, vb.net

Currently, My code does not properly detect if the string has a specific character.

for simple explanation. please refer to this:

`Dim strSample as String = "Y1-K99"`

and I tried this code if the string will detect if the `strSample` has a letter K.

```
If (strSample  Like "##K*" Or strSample Like "###K*") Then
'Do Something
End if
```

But It does not trigger or go to the Inside Function of the `If Else condition` even if it has a K.

Comment: Your variable name is `strSample`, but in `If` you use `sBMark`.

Comment: @JohnyL Sorry, My bad, I edit the sample sir.

Comment: @AlexisVillar Try Reading Examples in this [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator)

Comment: Ha-ha... `Like` is not supported in .NET Core... VS says so 

Comment: Thanks Sir! I get it now. Please paste it as an answer, so that i can accept it. and help anyone who has the same problem. @Unknown

Comment: @JohnyL But it work on me Sir.

Comment: It's because you use full .NET Framework.

Comment: But I wonder, is the condition so simple? For now it says: if string contains `K`, then OK. If it's so, then you could use: `If strSample.IndexOf("K") > 0`.

Comment: @AlexisVillar You already marked someone's answer.

Comment: @Unknown Ok Sir. But Thanks again for Helping me out. :) God Bless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are after "strSample has a letter K" 
, you will need to change your IF condition to be

```
If (strSample  Like "*K*") Then
'Do Something
End if
```

Have a read at this 
[Like Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator)

Comment: Thanks Sir! I already did cause @unknown teach me, and I will mark this as an answer. God Bless and Happy Coding :)